# Deconstruct API response with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

How do I deconstruct this API response with Typescript based on best practice?

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
// Setup Directus data fetching
const { $directus } = useNuxtApp()
import { Bestyrelse } from "~/types/bestyrelse.interface"

// Fetch bestyrelse data
const { data: bestyrelse }: Bestyrelse[] = await $directus.items("bestyrelse").readMany()
</script>
```

I'm getting `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Bestyrelse[]'`

Comment: You should have a member name after the keyword `const`. Example: `const myField: Array<Bestyrelse> = ....;` Also you usually need to wrap anything that uses `await` in a function/method marked with `async` but I am not sure if `vue.js` has some underlying magic it uses to do that for you (seeing as that is what you tagged).

Comment: What's the return type of `.readMany()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const { data: bestyrelse }: Bestyrelse[]` means `{ data: bestyrelse }` is of type `Bestyrelse[]`, which is obviously not an array. I guess you mean `data` is `Bestyrelse[]`, so it will be like this:

```
const { data: bestyrelse }: { data: Bestyrelse[] }
```